# The toilet flapper doesn't come down after the flush as it gets stuck and is a brand new flapper?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

The toilet flapper is brand new.
Putting a weight seems the only solution but not heavy enough to bring it down.

Comment: The  flapper should be loose, such that it falls down and closes if raised about a 70 degree angle. Does it?

Comment: Probably the chain is adjusted too short. The chain should be long enough so that it lifts the flapper off the opening just enough so that the flapper rises the rest of the way on its own by its own buoyancy. Then when the level of the water in the tank goes far enough down the flapper snaps back down and seals.

Comment: What kind of flapper? I'm guessing rather solid, as the floppy ones *can't not*. Get the kind that spins to let more or less air in that lets it close before it flushes the entire five gallons of water. But it's adjustable because the 1.5 or w/e isn't enough. And make sure it has a chain float, otherwise you'll have the reverse problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably misadjusted, being brand-new. Assuming the usual chain connection (as no pictures were provided) lengthen the chain so it's not pulled up so far.

If (as is the case for some replacement flappers) the hinge point is not fixed, raising that may also help.